# Can't figure out casting in onClick() method

Tags: android, casting, onclick, row, android-tablelayout

I have written an application that is designed to show report. The first screen of the application is a table that shows info (name, path) of the reports.

So I want to make the row of the table clickable in order to take me to the next screen where the detailed info of the report is displayed, and to know what is the corresponding report for the row. So I wrote my own row:

**TableReportRow:**

```
public class TableReportRow extends TableRow {

    Report report;

    public TableReportRow(Context context, Report report) {
        super(context);
        this.report = report;
    }

    public Report getReport() {
        return report;
    }

    public void setReport(Report report) {
        this.report = report;
    }
}
```

And then I created the table programmatically:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reports_list_activity_layout);
    application = (SGRaportManagerAppObj)getApplication();
    reportsRepository = application.reportsRepository.getReportsRepository();
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableReportsList);
    table.setStretchAllColumns(true);  
    table.setShrinkAllColumns(true);  
    final String tag = "tag";

    for (int i= 0; i < reportsRepository.size(); i++) {
        Report tempReport = reportsRepository.get(i);
        TableReportRow row = new TableReportRow(this, tempReport);
        // ...

        row.addView(tvName);
        row.addView(tvPath); 
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // This is where I need help.
            }
        });
        table.addView(row);
    }
```

Now I need to perform casting for the view in `onClick()` to get the access to the `GetReport()` method to get the actual corresponding report for the row, but I can't seem to get it right. Can some one help me with this one, please? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would guess as Report result = ((TableReportRow)v).getReport(); - or is that too obvious?

Comment: for some reason, eclipse would give me errors on that before cleanup but you right, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The View parameter in the onClick event is the View that the handler is bound to.  So in your case it will be an instance of TableReportRow, hence:

```
row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         TableReportRow local = (TableReportRow) v;
    }
});
```

Alternatively define your row as final in the outer block:

```
final TableReportRow row = new TableReportRow(this, tempReport);
...
row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         // row is in scope here
         row.getVirtualChildCount();
    }
});
```

Comment: what does getVirtualChildCount(); will produce for me?

Comment: Nothing.. it was just an example that you can call a method on the TableReportRow instance "AS" a TableReportRow instance

Answer (score 2):

You can cast it to a TableReportRow. When onClick is invoked, the view the listener is attached to is passed in as the parameter.

This is useful because it allows the same listener to be recycled for multiple buttons and you can identify the action on the view(based on text, contents, id, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

```
TableReportRow row = new TableReportRow(this, tempReport);
row.setId(i);//set an id for this.
//...
row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                        TableReportRow myRow=(TableReportRow)v;
                        int id=myRow.getId();//your id.
                        myRow.getReport();//yourReport
            }
        }
    });
```